# Update multiple objects using the Javascript map() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to refactor a ReactJS component by using a `map` function. Is it possible to use the `map()` function to update multiple objects, or the same object twice? I am getting a syntax error when trying to update the `initData` object as follows:

```
days.map(day => {
      return (
        initData[`${day}From`] = myStr.slice(0, 2) 
        initData[`${day}To`] = myStr.slice(5, 7)
      );
    });
```

Note that I need to use `return()` due to React. Note that this works with one object:

```
days.map(day => {
      return (
        initData[`${day}From`] = myStr.slice(0, 2) 
      );
    });
```

Comment: `initData `  where you have defined ?

Comment: It seems checking the code that you're using the wrong `'` charachter. Have you tried to fix it?

Comment: Why do you need to `return()` due to react?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not updating `day` itself and not modifying the `days` array, so there's no point using `map`. Just use a `for` or `forEach` loop.

```
days.forEach(day => {
        initData[`${day}From`] = myStr.slice(0, 2) 
        initData[`${day}To`] = myStr.slice(5, 7)
});
```