# Using .map method to update the object that I'm evaluating

Tags: javascript

I am executing the map method on an array `selectedItem` where `selectedItem` has a string property `nodeType` and an object property `items` :

`items = { computers: 0, drives: 0, files: 0, folders: 0 }`

```
selectedItem?.map(item => {
  switch (item.nodeType) {
    case 'FileType':
      return (items.files += 1);
    case 'FolderType':
      return (items.folders += 1);
    case 'DriveType':
      return (items.drives += 1);
    case 'ComputerType':
      return (items.computers += 1);
    default:
      return;
  }
```

I know I should be able to replace the switch statement by using the built-in functionality of the map method (`hasOwnProperty`), but I've only seen examples where Object literals are used to match on in order to return the string, like this:

```
const itemTypes = {
        file: 'file',
        folder: 'folder',
        drive: 'drive',
        computer: 'computer'
    }
```

However, upon a `.map(expression)` match I want to execute a simple incrementing logic to `+=1` to a property within the object I'm evaluating.

I've looked at `.filter()` and `.reduce()` but of course don't apply since they return a different array.  I'm sure it may have to deal with writing the correct function within the `.map(expression)` but not sure how to do that.

I've looked at these SO posts, but they either don't apply or don't get me all the way there.  The second link is very close to what I'm looking for but not sure how to apply it to my code:

- [Update multiple objects using Javascript map() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49896762/update-multiple-objects-using-the-javascript-map-function)
- [Update Map object property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278135/how-to-update-map-object-property-values)

How would I do that using only map and not nesting a switch within the map function?

Comment: If you are wanting to update an element, you would not use map.  `map()` is used to turn an array of things into an array of *other* things.  That's not your use case.

Comment: If you want to mutate the items in the array, rather than create a new array, use `forEach` (or a classic `for` loop).

Comment: map() makes no sense.... reduce would

Comment: Try using reduce, which will have the initial value to the JSON object ```items``` and at the end of the day it will return the updated ```items``` object. Reduce basically will accumulate the results on the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

map() is used to create a new array. It is not useful when you want to update an object.

You should be using reduce to count up all the types

```js
const selectedItem = [
 { nodeType: 'FolderType' },
 { nodeType: 'DriveType' },
 { nodeType: 'DriveType' },
 { nodeType: 'FolderType' },
 { nodeType: 'ComputerType' },
];
const types = {
  FileType: 'files',
  FolderType: 'folders',
  DriveType: 'drives',
  ComputerType: 'computers'
};

const items = {
  computers: 0,
  drives: 0,
  files: 0,
  folders: 0
};

selectedItem?.reduce((obj, item) => {
  const type = types[item.nodeType];
  if (type) obj[type]++;
  return obj;
}, items);

console.log(items);
```

or forEach

```js
const selectedItem = [
 { nodeType: 'FolderType' },
 { nodeType: 'DriveType' },
 { nodeType: 'DriveType' },
 { nodeType: 'FolderType' },
 { nodeType: 'ComputerType' },
];
const types = {
  FileType: 'files',
  FolderType: 'folders',
  DriveType: 'drives',
  ComputerType: 'computers'
};

const items = {
  computers: 0,
  drives: 0,
  files: 0,
  folders: 0
};

selectedItem?.forEach((item) => {
  const type = types[item.nodeType];
  if (type) items[type]++;
});

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **map object** to associate the node types to their items keys.

```
const itemsKeyByNodeType = {
  FileType: 'files',
  FolderType: 'folders',
  DriveType: 'drives',
  ComputerType: 'computers'
};

selectedItem?.forEach(item => {
  if (itemsKeyByNodeType[item.nodeType]) {
    items[itemsKeyByNodeType[item.nodeType]]++;
  }
});
```